# What is the equivalent of this snippet of Java code in C#?

Tags: java, c#, code-conversion

I stumbled upon this [website](http://www.theprojectspot.com/tutorial-post/creating-a-genetic-algorithm-for-beginners/3) and I am trying to test the idea, I don't know Java so I tried converting it to C#. Everything seems trivial but I get some exception while executing the sample.

I guess there must be something I am doing wrong here. The method which generates that exception is below :

```
 static void setSolution(String newSolution)
 {
        solution = new byte[newSolution.length()];
        // Loop through each character of our string and save it in our byte
        // array
        for (int i = 0; i < newSolution.length(); i++){
            String character = newSolution.substring(i, i + 1);
            if (character.contains("0") || character.contains("1")){
                solution[i] = Byte.parseByte(character);
            } else {
                solution[i] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is my C# based method:

```
public static void SetSolution(string newSolution)
{
    solution = new byte[newSolution.Length];
    // Loop through each character of our string and save it in our byte
    // array
    for (int i = 0; i < newSolution.Length; i++)
    {
        string character = newSolution.Substring(i, i + 1);
        if (character.Contains("0") || character.Contains("1"))
        {
            solution[i] = Byte.Parse(character);
        }
        else
        {
            solution[i] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Am I converting it correctly? since it doesn't make sense to convert, for example, 1000 to byte! as it is static the string retains its old values and thus in the 4th iteration it spits out an `OverFlow Exception`:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.OverflowException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Value was either too large or too small for an
>   unsigned byte.

I also tried

```
solution[i] =  Convert.ToByte(newSolution[i]);
```

which again doesn't seem to be it.

**Edit**

This is the input string:

```
 "1111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111"
```

Comment: Have you tried just implicitly converting it? `solution[i] = (byte) character;`?

Comment: I also don't understand, you're trying to set it to 0 if it contains 0, and 1 if it contains 1, and then 0 if it doesn't? Why can't you just change it to: if it contains 1, make it 1. Otherwise, make it 0.

Comment: What is your input string?

Comment: Are you sure the Java version works? `i+1` when `i == newSolution.length - 1` is out of bounds.

Comment: Compare the substring functions between java and C#, they don't convert over 1 for 1.

Comment: Since `character` will always have length 1, using `contains` in either language seems a bit heavy; also, you could just extract the first character (using `charAt` in Java) and subtract `'0'` from it (this has the value 48), instead of trying to find a parsing method.

Comment: I have zero knowledge of java, thats why i am trying to convert it to c#. I couldnt run it, so it thought making it a c# sample and testing it would be a better Idea!

Comment: I think this does exactly what the java code does: var bytes = newSolution.Select(c => (c == '0' || c == '1') ? byte.Parse(c.ToString()) : (byte)0).ToArray();

Comment: You are right, I will remove my comment!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The substring functions are not the same between Java and C#:

Java:

```
public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)
```

C#:

```
public string Substring(int startIndex, int length)
```

Convert this line to reflect what it's doing in Java.

The equivalent would be:

```
public static void SetSolution(string newSolution)
{
    solution = new sbyte[newSolution.Length];
    // Loop through each character of our string and save it in our byte
    // array
    for (int i = 0; i < newSolution.Length; i++)
    {
        string character = newSolution.Substring(i, 1); 
        if (character.Contains("0") || character.Contains("1"))
        {
            solution[i] = SByte.Parse(character);
        }
        else
        {
            solution[i] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer, however I'll nitpick: the Java 'byte' is signed, so the C# equivalent would be 'sbyte' and 'SByte.Parse'.

Comment: Good catch- I was simply looking for the root of the exception he was seeing, I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 5):

As the question stands how to convert to C#, I would personally use Linq:

```
public static void SetSolution(string newSolution)
{
    solution = newSolution.Select(c => c == '1' ? (byte)1 : (byte)0).ToArray();
}
```

I believe the above code should be functionally equivalent to your java snippet as basically all the characters except for '1' are converted to 0.